# Android WCF JSON result

Tags: android, json

For Synchronization purpose I wrote WCF service.That service return JSON as String Like this

{"Table1" : [{"BusinessUnit" : "SAMA","WarehouseCode" : "WWAT","LocationCode" : "WT03","ProductCode" : "500086","Stock" : "999.00","LastUpdatedOn" : "Jul 29 2011 11:25AM","LastUpdatedBy" : "WAT2 "}]}{"Table1" : ]}0{"Table1" : ]}{"Table1" : [{"BatchSerialNumber" : "1","BusinessUnit" : "SAMA","DateFrom" : "May 5 2011 12:00AM","DateTo" : "May 5 2100 2:53PM","Price" : "4.50","PriceGroup" : "WHSL","PricePer" : "1","ProductCode" : "501393","Quantity" : "1.00"},{"BatchSerialNumber" : "1","BusinessUnit" : "SAMA","DateFrom" : "May 5 2011 12:00AM","DateTo" : "May 5 2100 2:53PM","Price" : "33.79","PriceGroup" : "WHSL","PricePer" : "1","ProductCode" : "501817","Quantity" : "1.00"},{"BatchSerialNumber" : "1","BusinessUnit" : "SAMA","DateFrom" : "May 5 2011 12:00AM","DateTo" : "May 5 2100 2:53PM","Price" : "44.55","PriceGroup" : "WHSL","PricePer" : "1","ProductCode" : "603973","Quantity" : "1.00"},{"BatchSerialNumber" : "1","BusinessUnit" : "SAMA","DateFrom" : "May 5 2011 12:00AM","DateTo" : "May 5 2100 2:53PM","Price" : "4.39","PriceGroup" : "WHSL","PricePer" : "1","ProductCode" : "501736","Quantity" : "1.00"}

The Runtime only I know the fields & values.How can I get the fields list in android process methd

see my code [That comment place need to call field]

```
  public RDAlternativeProductDetail  getSoapResponseTableDataJson(SoapPrimitive node,
    ArrayList<String> strings) throws JSONException {
    String result = node.toString();
    JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(result);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    RDAlternativeProductDetail alternativeProductDetail = new   RDAlternativeProductDetail();
    JSONArray array = jsonobject.getJSONArray("BusinessUnit");
    int max = array.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        JSONObject tmp = array.getJSONObject(i);
       list.add(tmp.getString("//fileds place I want to call it"));
        ......
    }
    return RDAlternativeProductDetail ;
}
```

OR How to get all fields in the list? that means  BusinessUnit,WarehouseCode,LocationCode,ProductCode,Stock,LastUpdatedOn  like this

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Formatting of this article is very poor.  Please ensure that horizontal scrolling text is not present in the code samples.

Comment: I have done from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872396/android-json-result-processing

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by your comment. Also your JSON is invalid, try using http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0):

Look like you want to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object.

Try GSON: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/