# Android Json result processing

Tags: android, wcf, json

I have Json result like this: array.getJSONObject(j) --

> {"ExecutiveCode":"WAT2      ","FreeIssuePrefix":"
>   ","DisPaySchedulePrefix":"","NextFreeIssueNo":"1","NextReturnNo":"20","UploadedType":"1","DisNextFreeIssueNo":"1","DisNextFOCNo":"1","NextVisitNo":"15","DisNextOrderNo":"1","UploadedOn":"Jun
>   17 2011 
>   6:33PM","NextReturnAcceptNo":"1","BusinessUnit":"HEMA","TXNReferencePrefix":"20110708
>   ","OrderPrefix":"OR4 ","UploadedMethod":"3","FOCPrefix":"
>   ","ReturnPrefix":"RT4
>   ","RetailerPrefix":"TEM4","NextRetailerNo":"10","NextInvoiceNo":"1","NextGRNNo":"1","InvoicePrefix":"IN4
>   ","NextTXNReference":"2","NextOrderNo":"37","ReturnAcceptPrefix":"
>   ","PaySchedulePrefix":"PS4","NextReceiptNo":"1","NextFOCNo":"20","NextPayScheduleNo":"41","NextGRONo":"1","DisReturnPrefix":"
>   ","DisReceiptPrefix":"    ","DisNextReturnNo":"1","DisOrderPrefix":"
>   ","DisNextReceiptNo":"1","DisNextPayScheduleNo":"1","NextActivityNo":"1","DisInvoicePrefix":"
>   ","DisNextInvoiceNo":"1","UploadedBy":"WAT2","DisFreeIssuePrefix":"
>   ","DisFOCPrefix":"          ","ReceiptPrefix":"RP4 "}

And I have take vaue & name in the list:

I have written like this :

```
try {
  // getSoapResponseTableDataJson(responsePrimitiveData,
  // null,tablesName.get(i));
  String result = responsePrimitiveData.toString();
  JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(result);
  ArrayList<String> toFieldList = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> toFieldValList = new ArrayList<String>();
  JSONArray array = jsonobject.getJSONArray("Table1");
  int max = array.length();

  HashMap<String, String> applicationSettings = new HashMap<String, String>();
   for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
     System.out.println(" -- array.getJSONObject(j) -- "
        + array.getJSONObject(j));
     String value = array.getJSONObject(j).getString("value");
     String name = array.getJSONObject(j).getString("name");
     applicationSettings.put(name, value);
   }
  System.out.println(" ---- json --- "+ applicationSettings);
 } catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is saying :
 **org.json.JSONException : No value for value**

what is name & value?

Actually I want to get the Key separate list & value pair in separate list....
I want to take like this
       name like :  `{ExecutiveCode,FreeIssuePrefix,DisPaySchedulePrefix,.....}`
       value like :  `{WAT2, "","TEst",.....}`

Please help me.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: This is really good & correct answer.Buy mistake I cliked this boundry

Comment: How to rollback this points....Pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just think ... there is no `{"name": "something"}` in your JSON ...

**EDIT** ... i read wrong JSONObject documentation ... there is no JSONObject.getNames()

use obj.names()

```
JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(j);
JSONArray[] names = obj.names();
```

iterate names

```
String name = names.getString(i);
String value = obj.getString(name);
applicationSettings.put(name, value)
```

**old answer was**:

use:

```
JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(j);
String[] names = JSONObject.getNames(obj);
```

iterate names

```
value = obj.getString(names[i])
```

Comment: From my code, I have name & value. requirement is get the key & values in list or array.

Comment: Its not working.Please help me .I did like this `for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(j);
String[] names = array.getJSONObject(j).getNames(obj);
}`

Comment: can use like this :  Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    Iterator iter = menu.keys();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        String key = (String)iter.next();
        String value = menu.getString(key);
        map.put(key,value);
    } .. This one also error

Comment: i wrote all you need ... names are String array [ExecutiveCode,FreeIssuePrefix,DisPaySchedulePrefix]  .... iterate(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration) this array and call obj.getString(names[i]) within this iteration to obtain valuse for given name(name[i])

Comment: no **iterate names array** and use applicationSettings.put(names[i], obj.getString(names[i]) to fill hashmap ... it seems like you have really poor programming skills

Comment: JSONObject.getNames(obj) . is it predefine method. This place it showing error. Eclipse say : **The method getNames(JSONObject) is undefined for the type JSONObject** Please tell me How did you get it?

Comment: This is really good & correct answer.Buy mistake I cliked this boundry

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON parser libraries, it will save you tonnes of time.

1. [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
2. [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

Example: Parsing JSON in Jackson [here](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-json-parsing-made-easy-using-jackson/)

Comment: I have fixed this issue.Thanks by mistake I cliked this boundry

Comment: Android already has JSON parser - GSON and Jackson bring in pull parsing which is handy for big JSON files and some kind of databinding (which really saves time)